# Sending Random string/number with AJAX

Tags: ajax

I see that most of the sites send out a random number/string when making a request on the server.

Eg. yahoo mail will send something like this:

http://xxx.yahoo.com/mc/welcome?.gx=1&.tm=xxx&.rand=

What purpose does this serve?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a random number in query can prevent browser to cache the response.